# BitmapImage reference for ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, model-view-controller, reference

I convert a C # WPF application to ASP.Net core MVC.
In my model, I have this:

```
private BitmapImage picture;

[NotMapped]
public BitmapImage Picture
{
    get { return picture; }
    set
    {
        picture = value;
        NotifyPropertyChange();
        NotifyPropertyChange(nameof(CanViewPicture));
    }
}
```

But `BitmapImage` is not recognized, and I can not find the equivalent reference to `PresentationCore.dll` (framework 4.6.1) of the WPF project, to use `BitmapImage`. (`using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;`)

Someone knows, please?

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/01/19/net-core-image-processing/

Comment: Thanks you so much Kitson88